# Installing hudson slave on windows xp

Tags: hudson

I am trying to install a slave on windows xp on a different machine from the master.  I tried clicking on new node and it only give me the option of choosing dumb slave.  Is it supposed to be like that?  Anyway, I fill out the node name as "Test" and i select launch using jnlp and i hit save.  Now when I click on that node i download the slave-agent.jnlp and slave.jar files from that screen and i open a command prompt and enter  java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://servername:portnumber/hudson/computer/Test/slave-agent.jnlp but I get the following java errors:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) 
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) 
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:265) 
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:185)
```

When i try to run it from the web interface it cannot connect and it looks like it is trying to use a port number like 59870 instead of the real portnumber to connect to the host.  Does anyone know why I can't install the slave agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. You need to open that port number on the machine the master slave is on.